# ¿Qué significa esto en Angular 5?

Tags: html, angular5

Estoy haciendo un proyecto que ya estaba empezado en `angular`, me encontré con un código que no entiendo...

Podrían ayudarme por favor!

```
 <mz-checkbox-container class="check-option">
      <input mz-checkbox [label]="'CANCELLED' | translate" id="offline" (change)="setOffline($event.target.checked)" type="checkbox">
 </mz-checkbox-container>
```

No sé lo que significa:

> ($event.target.checked)

Alguien que me pueda dar una respuesta por favor!

Answer (score 2):

Viendo el código tu debes de tener una funcion `setOffline` defina, la cual obtiene un parámetro.

Dicho parametro es : `($event.target.checked)`, en cual basicamente dice que enviara el valor de tu `input`-`checkbox`, en este caso este sera un `boolean`, ya que `$event.target.checked` solo obtiene dos valores:

**true**=> cuando tu checkbox este marcado.

**false**=> cuando tu checkbox NO este marcado.

Espero haberte ayudado.